# How memory distribution happens in vertica plan steps?

Tags: query-optimization, vertica

I have a situation where a certain `vertica` query has `GROUP_BY_SPILLED` in its plan (doing a `GROUP BY HASH`).

I don't have an option to change the projection order by (to avoid group by hash), so I want to increase the amount of memory this step receives.

Let's say my query received budget of `5GB`.
How are the `5GB` distributed across the query steps?

I couldn't find any documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [EXECUTION_ENGINE_PROFILES](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/MONITOR/EXECUTION_ENGINE_PROFILES.htm) table.

Run your query with [PROFILE](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/PROFILE.htm?Highlight=PROFILE):

`PROFILE SELECT .. FROM .. GROUP BY ..`

Grab the statement_id from the output and use it to investigate EXECUTION_ENGINE_PROFILES.

Given a simple query that only does `GROUP BY`, run:

```
SELECT path_id,
       operator_name,
       counter_name,
       sum(counter_value)
FROM v_monitor.execution_engine_profiles
WHERE transaction_id=<STATEMENT_ID>
AND counter_name ilike 'current memory capacity (bytes)'
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY path_id;

 path_id | operator_name |          counter_name           |    sum     
---------+---------------+---------------------------------+------------
      -1 | NewEENode     | current memory capacity (bytes) |          0
      -1 | Root          | current memory capacity (bytes) |          0
       1 | ExprEval      | current memory capacity (bytes) |          0
       1 | GroupByHash   | current memory capacity (bytes) | 1406074880
       1 | GroupByPipe   | current memory capacity (bytes) |          0
       1 | ParallelUnion | current memory capacity (bytes) |          0
       1 | StorageUnion  | current memory capacity (bytes) |          0
       2 | ExprEval      | current memory capacity (bytes) |          0
       2 | Scan          | current memory capacity (bytes) |          0
```

More info about profiling in Vertica [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Profiling/ProfilingQueryPlanProfiles.htm%3FTocPath%3DAdministrator's%2520Guide%7CProfiling%2520Database%2520Performance%7CProfiling%2520Query%2520Plans%7C_____0)

I don't think you can modify or improve these counters  values, except increasing the query budget using [RESOURCE POOLS](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ManageWorkloads/ResourcePoolArchitecture.htm?Highlight=RESOURCE%20POOLs)